# .net MVC, SelectLists, and LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, selectlist

I am new to using the Html.DropDownList in the MVC framework and am having a hard time understading how to select the data out my database to bind to the DropDownList. Is there an easy way to return a bindable list (such as a SelectList) from a standard LINQ query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SelectList constructor takes an IEnumerable so all you need to do is pass the LINQ query to the constructor like so

```
 var query = from c in customers
                        select c;

 var customerList = new SelectList(query, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");
```

You should do this in the Controller and have the SelectList in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the `select` keyword in the LINQ query:

```
var foo = new SelectList(from x in FooRepository.Items
                         select new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id });
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I try to iterate the resulting SelectList as decsribed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5285272/1948038) and get only System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem as text and null as value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var foo = FoorePository.Items.Select(s = > new SelectListItem 
                                        {
                                          Text = s.Name, Value = s.Id.ToString()
                                        }
);
```

Sorry about formatting.