# What am i doing wrong with asp.net-mvc dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I use a dropdownlist in one of my create.aspx but it some how doesnt seem to work...

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FindAllMeasurements()
    {
        var mesurements = from mt in db.MeasurementTypes
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                             Value = mt.Id.ToString(),
                             Text= mt.Name
                          };
        return mesurements;
    }
```

and my controller,

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
      var mesurementTypes = consRepository.FindAllMeasurements().AsEnumerable();
     ViewData["MeasurementType"] = new SelectList(mesurementTypes,"Id","Name");
     return View();
    }
```

and my create.aspx has this,

```
<p>
  <label for="MeasurementTypeId">MeasurementType:</label>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("MeasurementType")%>
     <%= Html.ValidationMessage("MeasurementTypeId", "*") %>
   </p>
```

When i execute this i got these errors,

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a 
 property with the name 'Id'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller you are creating a new `SelectList` from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is not correct because you've already specified the `Value` and `Text` properties.

You have two options:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var mesurementTypes = consRepository.FindAllMeasurements();
    ViewData["MeasurementType"] = mesurementTypes;
    return View();
}
```

or:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["MeasurementType"] = new SelectList(db.MeasurementTypes, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

There's also a third and preferred way using strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var measurementTypes = new SelectList(db.MeasurementTypes, "Id", "Name");
    return View(measurementTypes);
}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("MeasurementType", Model, "-- Select Value ---") %>
```

Comment: @Ya darin that worked... How to add "Select" as 0th index in that list?

Comment: @PieterG How to add "Select" as 0th index in that list?

Comment: @Pandiya, you could use the proper extension method to add an optional label: `<%= Html.DropDownList("MeasurementType", "-- Please Select a Value ---")%>`

Comment: @Darin how to set value "0" to that "Select"

Comment: @when i inspected my select `<option value="">Select</option>`... I want to set `0` as value...

Comment: Using standard helpers this is not possible, you will have to insert a dummy element to your list at the beginning.

Comment: @Darin any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, you need an `IEnumerable<SelectList>`, not an `IEnumerable<Materials>`.

The constructor for SelectList has an overload that takes an IEnumerable.  See [.net MVC, SelectLists, and LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615583/net-mvc-selectlists-and-linq)

Comment: @Pandiya: Well, it's a completely different question now.  I see that you found `SelectList`.