# CheckboxList in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CheckboxList in MVC3 View and get the checked items passed to the controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller)

How do you create a checkboxlist in MVC3 and return the results that are checked on submit.

Asp.net MVC3

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's no helper built into the framework to do this for you. But it's not that difficult. Assuming that you already have a select list in ViewBag, this will work just fine.

```
@foreach (var o in ViewBag.Options) {
  <label><input type="checkbox"
         name="MyOptions"
         value="@o.Value"/>
  <span>@o.Text</span></label>
  <br/>
}
```

You view model will need to be able to accept an array, like this...

```
public class MyViewModel {
  public ICollection<string> MyOptions { get; set; }
}
```

The values selected will be in `MyOptions`.