# Send checkboxes values from a view to a controller in two steps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I've a two vanilla* html checkboxes in a Razor cshtml view.

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id="categorieOne" value="1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id="categorieTwo" value="2">
```

The first step would be to send this tags[] array to a controller.

The second step would be to get values 1 & 2 in seperated variables (example: in order to show "You've selected the following categories 1 ... 2" )

*By vanilla I mean they are not written with razor.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: have you seen the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285088/checkboxlist-in-mvc3

Comment: Yes I've tried why would I ask a question without trying anything ? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Meds what that usually means is that you need to post the source code of what you tried so that we can help you

Comment: @MauricioGracia I see but as it is a tiny part of code to perform that I don't know **how to realize** I would rather put nothing than an **invented and bad answer**, don't you agree ? However I can admit that my search regarding this question was pretty bad maybe this relate to this "trying".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rename your checkboxes from `tags[]` to `tags`, your controller action could take a string array as parameter which will hold the selected values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags" id="categorieOne" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags" id="categorieTwo" value="2" />
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string[] tags)
{
    ... the tags array will contain the selected values (1, 2, ...)
}
```